# How to store string array in sqlite database and keep order

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting, sqlite

i want to store a great amount of strings into my sqlite database. I want them to be always in the same order when i read them  as i add them to the database. I know i could give them an autoincrementing primary key and sort by that but since there can be up to 100.000 strings this is a performance issue. Besides the order should NEVER change or be sorted in any different way.

short example:

sql insert "hghtzdz12g"
sql insert "jut65bdt"
sql insert "lkk7676nbgt"

sql select * should give ALWAYS this order {"hghtzdz12g", "jut65bdt", "lkk7676nbgt" }

Any ideas how to achive this ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is a performance issue?

Comment: Sorting of thousands of strings might take a while or not ?

Comment: Yeah. A while - in miliseconds. This is 2014. Processors frequency is not mhz ;) a million rows was small 25 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a query like

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyColumn
```

the database does not need to sort the results if the column is indexed, because it can just scan through the index entries in order.

The `rowid` (or whatever you call the [autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) column) is an index, and is even more efficient than a separate index.

Comment: If i understand you right this "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS strings (name TEXT)" should be enough ? I am just starting to learn about database handling and i am no shure if i understand the rowid thing correct. Does any table have a rowid or do i have to specify that when i create the table?

Comment: You'd have to say [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) to omit the rowid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you will never need anything but exactly this array in exactly this order, you can cheat the database and put in a single blob field.

But then you should ask yourself why you chose a database in the first place.

The correct database solution is indeed a table using a key that you can sort by.

If this performance is not enough, you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite) for performance hints.

If you need ultra-fast performance, maybe a database is not the best tool for the job. Databases are used for their [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) abilities and speed is not one of them but rather a secondary objective of everything in software.